# can we declare a function inside of eventlistner and call it from outside?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, validation, addeventlistener

Here I have declared a function "driverDetailsValidation" within the event listener. I want to call it from outside the event listener. This is the code which I have used but it doesn't work

```
driverType.onchange = function(e) {
        var isWithoutDriver = (driverType.value == "without driver");
        if(!isWithoutDriver){
            driverDetailsValidation();
        }
    }

    const driver_fields = document.getElementsByClassName("driver_fields");
    
    form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
        validity = true;
    
        function driverDetailsValidation() {
            for (let i = 0; i < driver_fields.length; i++) {
                if (driver_fields[i].value == "") {
                    driver_fields[i].style.border = "2px solid rgb(228, 29, 22)";
                    driver_fields[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(238, 156, 156, 0.788)";
                    //fields[i].placeholder = "This Field is Compulsory!";
                    validity = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of declaring a function inside an eventListener if you want to use it outside its scope? Why don't create the function in the global scope?

Comment: This sounds like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think you want to do this? It's *possible* to declare it in the event handler and assign it to a variable declared outside the event handler and call it via that variable, but only after the event has happened at least once, and it's a very suspect thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare a variable outside the event listener and assign the function to it inside the listener. Then, you can call the function from the variable like this:

```js
var fct;

document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", function() {
  fct = function() {
    alert("Working");
  }
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (fct != null) {
    fct();
    fct = null;
  }
}, 0);
```

```html
<div>
Click me
</div>
```

But it doesn't really make sense, I think.